# Best way to use Category & Custom Fields?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I have a website called http://overmvp.com. On this site, there are multiple "Heroes". Each hero has been manually added to the database in a custom table.

With this, I need to create a guide. So for example, I would need to be able to create a guide for a specific "Hero". For that, I've created a custom post type called "Guides", and also a Taxonomy. In the Taxonomy, I've re-added all the "Heroes" that I've previously added in the database. (So they are not duplicated) So now, I can create a guide for a specific hero.

But now my problem is that I have to add more types to a guide. So for example, I want to show "Guides" of a specific type of "Hero". So I need to write down the type of that hero somewhere.

As with "Hero Types", I would also need to be able to mark them as, featured guide or things like that.

My first guess was to add a custom field to the Taxonomy, so for every hero, I would add the type of the hero, but I fell that I am duplicating the heroes, types, pretty much every information they have.

So is there another way I should incorporate the "Heroes" into my website, so I can use them in my custom post type directly and not duplicate them like I do ?

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you are trying to do here, could you add an example of  how this might work for the user?   I think you are going in the right direction with a custom post type, but I'm not quite sure how you want your data to connect up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a wrong answer.

It is posted in other question.

About your situation,

Heroes seem like Category(Custom Taxonomy)

Guides is a custom post (Custom post)

About Heroes Type, it can be a subcategory of Heroes or you can create new custom taxonomy for it.

In custom post, you just need to embed Heroes Types and Heroes if you have 2 different custom taxonomy.

More simple, you can use guides meta to save values (just like postmeta).

Taxonomy can be embed anywhere in  any custom post. It depend on your idea and your data structure.

Comment: In general, we have our heroes section already builded with all the information each hero need. So for example Hero 1 is Type 1, Hero 2 is Type 2 ...

User on the website will be able to create guide, so if they chose Hero 1, the guide will have Type 1 assign to it. 

Here is a screenshot describing it a little http://puu.sh/mxlIz/2d509a4267.png

The hero is on the left, the little shield is the type, there is the guide name so when we click on it, we access the guide.

So then we would like to filter guides by type (on top), check this image https://gyazo.com/91256feb668afd2e99e9690209eeafdd

Comment: You can use ajax to process this problem. Data will be filtered by heroes and type.

Comment: Alright I understand, but I mean that all my data will be like "duplicated" on my website if I keep it like that because, I have all my "Heroes" in a database table, but I have to write them again in my Taxonomy, so with my Custom Post Type, I can select the "Hero" I want. Is there another way I could do this so I don't duplicate my Data ?